# cfx Firefox add-on with panel not opening tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to make an add-on to open a tab with a specific link based on an input from the panel (which contains a text field).
The problem is: I never used any programming language before.

When the user presses "Return" it should send whatever was into the text field to the main script. But the only thing that happens is that it resets the field value, without opening any tab.

This is the embedded script in the panel:

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('edit-box');
textArea.addEventListener("keypress", onkeypress)

function onkeypress(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    textArea.setAttribute('tabindex', 0);
    text = textArea.value.replace(/\r?\n/gm,"");
    addon.port.emit("text-entered", text);
    textArea.value = '';
  }
}
```

And this is the main script, where it should open the tab:

```js
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var ui = require("sdk/ui");
var {
  ToggleButton
} = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  width: 300,
  height: 169,
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {
    checked: false
  });
}

function handleClick(state) {
  text_entry.show();
}

var text_entry = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});

text_entry.on("show", function() {
  text_entry.port.emit("show");
});

text_entry.port.on("text-entered", function(text) {
  console.log(text);
  text_entry.hide();
  tabs.open("http://www.example.com/" + text + ".html");
});
```

Now, how do i make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `keypress` event to `keyup`:

you have:

```
textArea.addEventListener("keypress", onkeypress)
```

make it:

```
textArea.addEventListener("keyup", onkeypress)
```

keypress doesnt have `e.keyCode` i dont think